# Having build path problems after importing AppCompat library

Tags: android, dependencies, android-appcompat

I'm trying to design a simple hello world application with material design using Appcompat. I imported the v7 libraries into the workspace (I use eclipse btw) but after this, my other projects and also this one started showing this red exclamation mark indicating build path problems. when I checked it, the android dependencies in project>properties>Java build path was showing an error. Removing android dependencies would temporarily remove the exclamation but android dependencies would rebuild and bring the errors all over again. when i run my material application, i get the following error "
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" i tried rebuilding the library but got the same problems. what am i doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using API21/22 to compile?

Answer (score 0):

- You delete support v7 lib on current workspace
- Project -> properties -> remove inclused v7 lib
- Clean project
- reimport v7 lib from SDK-DIRECTORY/extras/android/support/v7/combat
- click "v7 on your workspace" -> Properties -> click to choose "is Library" if it not be checked.
- Android Project -> properties -> add lib -> choose "v7 on your workspace"
- Reclean project.

-> Wait -> OK

Comment: Have any android-support-v7-appcompat.jar  in libs directory of your project?

Comment: Yes. I had copied it to my project's libs folder.

Comment: So, this is your problem. If you included suppor v7 project lib from current workspace, you couldn't import android-support-v7-appcompat.jar. Because  Android SDK will throw "multi dex file Exception".

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the answer myself (eclipse did it btw). it was that i had to rename all the jars of the support libraries in their bin folders to match what it said it should be in project->properties->java build path->android dependencies. like my support library for appcompat was named something similar to appcompat-v7-support and its jar held the same name. eclipse said that appcompat-v7.jar was missing from the bin folder so all i had to do was rename my jar. Fairly simple yet annoying. i leave this post for others to refer.